# How to join two DataTables into another DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

i have two data tables `table1` and `table2`. I want to join them resulting in another data table in `C#`. All the columns of both the tables are not known.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var joinTables = from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on t1["S_InstanceID"] equals t2["P_ID"]
                 select new { T1 = t1, T2 = t2 };
```

**Note:** there is no column of same name in both tables

`table1` will always have only one row, but `table2` can have any number of rows.

All columns are not known, only `S_InstanceID` from `table1` and `P_ID` from `table2` are known which have to be used for join relation

Currently in `joinTables` var, I am getting only `anonymous DataRow` - how can I get it in the `DataTable` format?

Comment: I need to add both of them column wise merge is used for row wise merging of DataTable

Comment: for join we need to have a common column for both the table so why do it need primary keys

Comment: Datatable.Merge(DataTable, Boolean, MissingSchemaAction) does not work?

Comment: dont have any idea about it @FalcoAlexander but i need to add them coulmwise

Comment: merge will add the colums if you want, but the tables probably need to be part of a `DataSet` with FK contraints.

Comment: Yes P_ID is the foreign key in table t2

Comment: simply try it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension method for converting from LINQ result back to `DataTable` specifically for `join`:

```
// Create new DataTable from LINQ results on DataTable
// Expect T to be anonymous object of form new { DataRow d1, DataRow d2, ... }
public static DataTable FlattenToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) {
    var res = new DataTable();
    if (src.Any()) {
        var firstRow = src.First();
        var rowType = typeof(T);
        var memberInfos = rowType.GetPropertiesOrFields();
        var allDC = memberInfos.SelectMany(mi => mi.GetValue<DataRow>(firstRow).Table.DataColumns());

        foreach (var dc in allDC) {
            var newColumnName = dc.ColumnName;
            if (res.ColumnNames().Contains(newColumnName)) {
                var suffixNumber = 1;
                while (res.ColumnNames().Contains($"{newColumnName}.{suffixNumber}"))
                    ++suffixNumber;
                newColumnName = $"{newColumnName}.{suffixNumber}";
            }
            res.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(newColumnName, dc.DataType));
        }

        foreach (var objRows in src)
            res.Rows.Add(memberInfos.SelectMany(mi => mi.GetValue<DataRow>(objRows).ItemArray).ToArray());
    }
    return res;
}

// ***
// *** Type Extensions
// ***
public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
    t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field | mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();

// ***
// *** MemberInfo Extensions
// ***
public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}
public static T GetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) => (T)member.GetValue(srcObject);
```